# Oozie sqoop task error: Cannot run program "hive": error=2 no such file or directory

Tags: hive, sqoop, oozie, bigdata

i created a oozie sqoop task to import data from mysql to hive. i have a namenode and 3 datanodes, which also have hive, oozie and sqoop installed on the namenode.

the sqoop import coommand has been tested var CLI on the namenode, but every time i create a oozie sqoop task, it also aways failed. below is the detail errors.

`2017-08-11 11:27:40,787 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 0% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:40,787 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 0% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:44,833 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 25% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:44,833 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 25% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:45,837 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 75% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:45,837 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 75% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:46,844 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:46,844 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 0%
2017-08-11 11:27:46,856 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1502360348741_0041 completed successfully
2017-08-11 11:27:46,856 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1502360348741_0041 completed successfully
...
2017-08-11 11:27:46,932 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Transferred 625 bytes in 12.0595 seconds (51.8263 bytes/sec)
2017-08-11 11:27:46,936 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Retrieved 14 records.
2017-08-11 11:27:46,951 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM UserRole AS t WHERE 1=0
2017-08-11 11:27:46,952 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM UserRole AS t WHERE 1=0
2017-08-11 11:27:46,953 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.hive.TableDefWriter  - Column updatedDate had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
2017-08-11 11:27:46,960 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading uploaded data into Hive
2017-08-11 11:27:46,963 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=2,`

here are my thoughts

1. the mapper job is generated, so this script should be submitted and run on namenode. is this correct?
2. i am all the env vars config well, so the error phase, which import tool to import data to the hive table should be launched on one of the datanode.

so should i install hive on every datanode of the cluster? or is there any config that i can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: copy hive-site of your cluster to oozie lib folder

Comment: Can you post your oozie `workflow.xml`

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure hive-site.xml is at place in the hdfs.
2. Copy all hive libs shared folder to sqoop libs shared folder.